# Why flutter tooltip not worked

Tags: flutter, dart

I have faced the flutter `tooltip` problem

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  String _value = 'Hello again';

  void _onClicked() => setState(() => _value = new DateTime.now().toString());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // key: _scaffoldstate,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Name here'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_value),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
                onPressed: _onClicked,
                tooltip: "Hi I'm tooltip", // way one
              ),
              Tooltip(
                // way two
                message: 'I am a Tooltip',
                child: Text('Hover over the text to show a tooltip.'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried two way but doesn't work in any way, I don't know where is a problem.

Is it a problem with my column widget?

flutter `version: 2.0.3`

any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 2):

ToolTips gets visible when you hover on those Widgets. In a mobile phone, it's not possible to hover on widgets without a mouse so try long pressing on those widgets to view tooltips.

ToolTips are visible when hovering on those widgets on the web. Check this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/2956e62940ac3e8506a1e677ac6c7ac6)

Comment: Thank you, it's my bad, maybe my virtual device was too much slow, that's why I can't see.